# como puedo resolver null pointer exception en la instalación de web logic 12?

Tags: java, weblogic

estoy intentando instalar Weblogic 12 (v 12.2.1.4.0) en un mac M1 y al momento de ejecutar el comando en consola me sale el siguiente error:

```
El archivo log del iniciador es /private/var/folders/mm/grq8pvrd0m30p6v70p7_sfrm0000gp/T/OraInstall2024-01-22_11-15-52AM/launcher2024-01-22_11-15-52AM.log.
Extrayendo instalador... . . Listo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inventory.InventoryUtils.getDefaultInvPtrLoc(InventoryUtils.java:131)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.PlatformHelper.getDefaultInventoryPointerFile(PlatformHelper.java:503)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Utils.getInvPtrLoc(Utils.java:449)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.doMainHelper(Launcher.java:2346)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:4119)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:3981)
```

lo intente ejecutar con distintas versiones de java 11 y 8 pero el error persiste.

comando para intalacion de Weblogic:`java -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_lite_generic_ARM_OCI.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic 12 (v 12.2.1.4.0) **[de acuerdo a la documentación es compatible con Java EE 7](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/intro/compatibility.html#GUID-A8ABF11F-230E-4959-9B91-8AE1E7E43750)**

> Compatibilidad con Java EE 7 WebLogic Server 12c (12.2.1.4.0) es
> compatible con Java EE 7. Esta compatibilidad permite que una
> aplicación compatible con Java EE 7 se desarrolle en una plataforma de
> sistema operativo y se implemente para producción en otra, sin
> requerir cambios en el código de la aplicación Java EE 7.
>
> Oracle garantiza esta compatibilidad de la portabilidad de
> aplicaciones Java EE 7 dentro de un nivel de versión de WebLogic
> Server.

por lo que debes usar esta versión de Java y también asegura que las variables de entorno `JAVA_HOME` y `PATH` se encuentren configuradas correctamente.

Comment: hola, gracias por la información, pero la solución fue instalar Weblogic con la version especifica de java 1.8.0_202 de oracle, probe con muchas versiones de java 8 pero esa fue la que si me permitió instalarlo

Comment: Si @Eve, eso es otra solución, pero si usas la versión v 12.2.1.4.0 que indicas en tu pregunta, debes usar Java EE 7, saludos!